# Replace string in textarea on click and then copy (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form with a `textarea` and a `button`. If someone enters a text in the textarea and clicks the button, I want the function to search for if "Tobias" was entered in the textarea and if so, replace it with "Hanna" and finally copy it to the clipboard.

If I enter this in the textarea...

> Tobias is great!

...and then click the button; I want this to be copied to the clipboard:

> Hanna is great!

But it won't work. This is the code so far:

```
$("button").click(function(){
var $textArea = $("textarea");
var $newText = $textArea.val().replace("Tobias", "Hanna");
    $newText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

Comment: Hm, not sure that var/string you create can be selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a `.select()` on a string. As per [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/select/#select), its use is limited to `<input type="text">` and `<textarea>` elements.

Perhaps what you're looking for is something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6mz4qyL0/3/

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var $textArea = $("textarea");
    var oldText = $textArea.val();
    var newText = oldText.replace("Tobias","Hanna");
    $textArea.val(newText).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    $textArea.val(oldText);
});
```

This changes the textarea value to the replacement text, copies it, and then changes it back, all without the user knowing.

---

Additionally as a friendly note... While there is nothing *syntactically* incorrect with your `$newText` variable, I'd personally suggest dropping the `$` from its name.

When working with a block of jQuery code, those familiar with the language will most likely assume that a variable prefixed with `$` refers to a jQuery object/array. In your case, `$newText` is a basic `string`, so it's quite deceiving.

Comment: Thanks! Worked exactly like I wanted it to! Is there any way to add more words that I want replaced? Let's say I enter "Tobias is great!" and I want the output to be "Hanna is lovely!", replacing "Tobias" with "Hanna" and "great" with "lovely".

Comment: And yeah, I really appreciate the friendly note. I've seen that way of naming variables in tutorials, but obviously never understood the meaning of doing so. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. For other replaces, you can just keep appending them to the replace that's already there. `.replace("Tobias", "Hanna").replace("great", "lovely")`. If you're going to have a bunch of these down the line, you may want to look into listing the replacements in an object to be more concise.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you once again!

Comment: @tobiasg When you set a variable to a JQuery wrapped set (i.e. `var $elements = $("div");` it is a good idea to prefix the variable with `$` to remind you that the variable is referencing a JQuery object and not a regular JavaScript node list.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to cache the original value and then put the new value into an element that is selectable so that you can copy the selected text. Then you can put back the original text.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var original = $("textarea").val();
  var updated = $("textarea").val().replace("Tobias", "Hanna");
  $("textarea").val(updated);
  $("textarea").select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  $("textarea").val(original);
});
```

```css
input[type=text] { height:1px, width:1px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Tobias is great</textarea>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I don't think that OP wants the textbox's value to *show* the replacement. It seems like it's more of a deception: You think you're copying the textarea, but what you've copied is actually altered to replace the name.